# How do I Extract All The XML Values from a Variable using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the XML Variable Below & I want to extract out all the values in DATA:

```
DECLARE @Xml XML = '<MetaData type="Contracts">
  <Data column="PositionName">Administrator- Contract Compl</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Administrator - Contract Compl</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Dir - Contract Adm &amp; Analytics</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Director - Commercial Support</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Lead Contract Admin - Compl</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Lead Contract Administrator</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Assoc- Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Contract Administrator</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Director- Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Lead Contract Administrator</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Manager- Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Manager - Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Rep - NGL Distribution</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Supervisor- Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">VP- Contract Administration</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Associate Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Sr Manager - Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Sr Specialist - Producer Svcs</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Supervisor - Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Supervisor - Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">VP - Contract Administration</Data>
</MetaData>';
```

-- This fails

```
SELECT
    x.v.value('Data[1]','VARCHAR(100)')
FROM @Xml.nodes('MetaData/Data') x(v)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this query satisfies your requirements:

```
SELECT
    x.v.value('.','VARCHAR(100)')
FROM @Xml.nodes('MetaData/Data') x(v)
```

The issue is that using `'Data[1]'` will return only the element at index position 1, but the period `'.'` will return all values. Also it's slightly malformed as there is no 'MetaData/Data/Data[1]' node (that's why you got all `NULL` values previously).

Answer (score 0):

**Please use this**

```
    DECLARE @Xml XML = '<MetaData type="Contracts">
  <Data column="PositionName">Administrator- Contract Compl</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Administrator - Contract Compl</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Dir - Contract Adm &amp; Analytics</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Director - Commercial Support</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Lead Contract Admin - Compl</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Lead Contract Administrator</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Assoc- Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Contract Administrator</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Director- Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Lead Contract Administrator</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Manager- Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Manager - Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Rep - NGL Distribution</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Supervisor- Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">VP- Contract Administration</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Associate Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Sr Manager - Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Sr Specialist - Producer Svcs</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Supervisor - Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Supervisor - Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">VP - Contract Administration</Data>
</MetaData>'
DECLARE @m TABLE  (Xmls XML)
INSERT INTO @m SELECT @XML 
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
           p.value(N'.',N'nvarchar(MAX)') AS [Id]             
    FROM @m as x
    OUTER APPLY x.Xmls.nodes(N'/MetaData/Data') AS u(p)        
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Id
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator- Contract Compl
Administrator - Contract Compl
Dir - Contract Adm & Analytics
Director - Commercial Support
Lead Contract Admin - Compl
Lead Contract Administrator
Assoc- Contract Admin
Contract Administrator
Director- Contract Admin
Lead Contract Administrator
Manager- Contract Admin
Manager - Contract Admin
Rep - NGL Distribution
Supervisor- Contract Admin
VP- Contract Administration
Associate Contract Admin
Sr Manager - Contract Admin
Sr Specialist - Producer Svcs
Supervisor - Contract Admin
Supervisor - Contract Admin
VP - Contract Administration

(21 rows affected)
```

**I have also changed your code to working. You have mentioned the Data twice**

```
DECLARE @Xml XML = '<MetaData type="Contracts">
  <Data column="PositionName">Administrator- Contract Compl</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Administrator - Contract Compl</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Dir - Contract Adm &amp; Analytics</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Director - Commercial Support</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Lead Contract Admin - Compl</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Lead Contract Administrator</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Assoc- Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Contract Administrator</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Director- Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Lead Contract Administrator</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Manager- Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Manager - Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Rep - NGL Distribution</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Supervisor- Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">VP- Contract Administration</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Associate Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Sr Manager - Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Sr Specialist - Producer Svcs</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Supervisor - Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">Supervisor - Contract Admin</Data>
  <Data column="PositionName">VP - Contract Administration</Data>
</MetaData>'
SELECT
    x.v.value('.','VARCHAR(100)')
FROM @Xml.nodes('/MetaData/Data') x(v)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator- Contract Compl
Administrator - Contract Compl
Dir - Contract Adm & Analytics
Director - Commercial Support
Lead Contract Admin - Compl
Lead Contract Administrator
Assoc- Contract Admin
Contract Administrator
Director- Contract Admin
Lead Contract Administrator
Manager- Contract Admin
Manager - Contract Admin
Rep - NGL Distribution
Supervisor- Contract Admin
VP- Contract Administration
Associate Contract Admin
Sr Manager - Contract Admin
Sr Specialist - Producer Svcs
Supervisor - Contract Admin
Supervisor - Contract Admin
VP - Contract Administration

(21 rows affected)
```

Comment: I need ALL the DATA values...NOT just the FIRST one...thanks

Comment: You want those in single column.